# Webpack + React + multiple SVG loaders issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

```
{
  test: /\.svg/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'url-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'svg-react-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

This is `module: { rules: [` section regarding SVG loaders in my `webpack.config.js`

Anyone used similar setup and had issues with importing svg files in React?

I need both to load svg in CSS and to import them in React.
If I use

- url-loader alone CSS works.
- If I use svg-react-loader alone imports in React works.

But together imports in React fails with the following error:

```
Module build failed: Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
```

Here is how I import the SVG in React cmp:

```
import StarIcon from 'svg-react-loader!mdi-svg/svg/star.svg';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the cleanest way to handle loaders without a need to reference the loader in the actual JS / CSS code during the imports is to use oneOf with exclude property:

```
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      oneOf: [
        {
          exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
          use: 'svg-react-loader'
        },
        {
          exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/'),
          use: 'url-loader'
        },
      ],
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to use `oneOf`, but with `include` option, which is logically more correct, than `exclude` option:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  oneOf: [
    {
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/'),
      use: 'svg-react-loader'
    },
    {
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
      use: 'url-loader'
    },
  ],
}
```